# How to invoke IAM authorized AWS ApiGateway endpoint from lambda?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-iam, apollo-server

I'm trying to invoke an AWS ApiGateway HTTP endpoint from a lambda function that I've secured using an IAM authorizer, however I cannot for the life of me get anything from my lambda function to work.

I've tested the endpoint with Postman, and can confirm that it works when I select "AWS Signature" as the Authorization type and put in my local credentials, so it's not an issue with how the endpoint is set up. It must be an issue with how I am sending the request from Lambda. The additional challenge is adding the headers to a GraphQL API request.

This is what my lambda function looks like:

```
import { ApolloServer } from 'apollo-server-lambda';
import { APIGatewayProxyEvent, Callback, Context } from 'aws-lambda';
import { ApolloGateway, RemoteGraphQLDataSource } from '@apollo/gateway';
import aws4 from 'aws4';

const userServiceUrl = process.env.USER_SERVICE_URL;
const {hostname, pathname} = new URL(userServiceUrl);

class AuthenticatedDataSource extends RemoteGraphQLDataSource {
  willSendRequest({request}) {
    console.log('request is: ', request);
    const opts: Record<string, any> = {
      service: 'execute-api',
      region: process.env.AWS_REGION,
      host: hostname,
      path: pathname,
      body: JSON.stringify({query: request.query}),
      method: 'POST'
    }
    aws4.sign(opts);
    console.log('opts are: ', opts);
    request.http.headers.set('X-Amz-Date', opts.headers['X-Amz-Date']);
    request.http.headers.set('Authorization', opts.headers['Authorization']);
    request.http.headers.set('X-Amz-Security-Token', opts.headers['X-Amz-Security-Token']);
  }
}
```

No matter what I try I always get a 403 forbidden error and the request never makes it to the actual endpoint behind the authorizer. I've tried removing body, I've tried hardcoding my local credentials into the aws4 call, none of it works. My hunch is that my signature call is wrong somehow, but when I compare it to the few examples I've found on the internet I can't see anything obviously wrong.

Any resources that could point me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. Most of the examples I find are front end specific so I know that could possibly be steering me wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `willSendRequest` function is not the best place to sign the request as apollo-server can modify the request object after `willSendRequest` is invoked.
Instead you should implement a custom fetch and pass it to the `RemoteGraphQLDataSource` constructor to ensure that you are signing the final request before it is sent.

your custom `GraphQLDataSource` with custom fetch would be *something* like this:

```
import { Request, RequestInit, Response, fetch, Headers } from "apollo-server-env";
import aws4 from 'aws4';
import { RemoteGraphQLDataSource } from '@apollo/gateway';

class AuthenticatedDataSource extends RemoteGraphQLDataSource {
    public constructor(
        url: string,
    ) {
        super({
            url: url,
            fetcher: doFetch,
        });
    }

    async doFetch(
        input?: string | Request | undefined,
        init?: RequestInit | undefined
    ): Promise<Response> {
        const url = new URL(input as string);
        const opts: Record<string, any> = {
            service: 'execute-api',
            region: process.env.AWS_REGION,
            host: url.hostname,
            path: url.pathname,
            body: init?.body,
            method: init?.method
        }
        aws4.sign(opts);
        init.headers.set('X-Amz-Date', opts.headers['X-Amz-Date']);
        init.headers.set('Authorization', opts.headers['Authorization']);
        init.headers.set('X-Amz-Security-Token', opts.headers['X-Amz-Security-Token']);
        const response = await fetch(input, init);

        return response;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I finally got it working! After changing it to this I was able to get it to work by overriding all of the headers instead of just the 3 I set. (See my answer for what I changed)

Answer (score 0):

For prosperity, this is what I ended up doing and works flawlessly (Thank you so much Glen Thomas!)

```
import { Request, RequestInit, Response, fetch } from "apollo-server-env";
import { ApolloServer } from 'apollo-server-lambda';
import { APIGatewayProxyEvent, Callback, Context } from 'aws-lambda';
import { ApolloGateway, RemoteGraphQLDataSource } from '@apollo/gateway';
import aws4 from 'aws4';

const userServiceUrl = process.env.USER_SERVICE_URL;

async function doFetch(
  input?: Request | string,
  init?: RequestInit
): Promise<Response> {
  const urlString = typeof input === 'string' ? input : input.url;
  const url = new URL(urlString);
  const opts: Record<string, any> = {
    service: 'execute-api',
    region: process.env.AWS_REGION,
    host: url.hostname,
    path: url.pathname,
    body: init?.body,
    method: init?.method
  }
  aws4.sign(opts);
  init.headers = opts.headers;
  const response = await fetch(input, init);

  return response;
}

class AuthenticatedDataSource extends RemoteGraphQLDataSource {
  constructor(url: string) {
    super({
      url,
      fetcher: doFetch
    })
  }
}

const server = new ApolloServer({
  gateway: new ApolloGateway({
    serviceList: [
      { name: 'users', url: userServiceUrl }
    ],
    buildService({url}) {
      return new AuthenticatedDataSource(url)
    }
  }),
  subscriptions: false,
  introspection: true,
  playground: true,
});

export const handler = (event: APIGatewayProxyEvent, context: Context, callback: Callback) => {
  console.log('event is: ', JSON.stringify(event, null, 2))
  
  return server.createHandler({
    cors: {
      origin: '*'
    }
  })(event, context, callback);
}
```

Comment: Another tip for anyone who finds this is to always test with a wildcard IAM policy, then make it stricter after you have it working. I think I might have messed things up by using what I thought was a valid resource qualifier.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, `willSendRequest` works fine, and is preferred for simplicity. For cases you want to sign the request for specific data sources with an easy setup.

The reason why the documented attempts failed is because the request signing needs to be exact: Path must contain both the path & query parameters. `https` is also stripped as the corresponding AWS signature error indicated the host to not have one.

### GET request

```
  willSendRequest(request: RequestOptions) {
    const query = request.params ? `?${request.params.toString()}` : "";
    const opts: Record<string, any> = {
      service: "execute-api",
      region: process.env.AWS_REGION,
      host: this.baseURL?.replace("https://", ""),
      path: request.path + query,
      method: request.method,
    };

    sign(opts);

    request.headers.set("X-Amz-Date", opts.headers["X-Amz-Date"]);
    request.headers.set("Authorization", opts.headers["Authorization"]);
    request.headers.set(
      "X-Amz-Security-Token",
      opts.headers["X-Amz-Security-Token"]
    );
  }
```

### POST Request

Fragment example, from another JS lambda (not apollo-graphql) having a body; not sure if apollo automatically decodes the body, regardless it's a good example to showcase.

```
  if (Object.hasOwnProperty.call(request, 'body')) {
    const { data, encoding } = request.body;
    const buffer = Buffer.from(data, encoding);
    const decodedBody = buffer.toString('utf8');

    if (decodedBody !== '') {
      normalisedRequest.body = decodedBody;
      normalisedRequest.headers = { 'content-type': request.headers['content-type'][0].value };
    }
  }
```

Comment: Just found this question.  I had gone down the path of implementing a custom fetcher and went back to test out just signing in `willSendRequest`.  While I did get it to work, there's a catch as mentioned by Turner Houston regarding the shape of the payload is not guaranteed in willSendRequest() as you have to build it from the provided props.  However the body is given in the Fetcher.  The signing process I'm using (aws4) also requires the body to be signed for a POST request and that's where you need to make sure the payload isn't going to change.